# An empty option for bs-select

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-strap

I am using [AngularStrap](http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/) in my project.
I can add an empty option for select tag:

```
<select data-ng-options="..." data-ng-model="...">
    <option value=""></option>
</select>
```

But how to do it in a single bs-select?

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-model="model"
        data-html="1" data-animation="am-flip-x" placeholder="Choose..."
        ng-options="value.Id as value.Name for value in values" bs-select>
    Action <span class="caret"></span>
</button>
```

It doesn't help me:

```
values.unshift({Id:null, Name: ''});
```

Comment: Are you expecting this http://plnkr.co/edit/ghtu4re7dYidsoP47Bij?p=preview ?

Comment: No, I want to see "Choose..." when I select an empty option (set model = null). Should I implement my custom template?

Comment: Now I cant open plunkr due to that site is busy (loading...) you just try to add null for value text for choose..